# Convert sparse array column pointers (colptr) to column indices in julia

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

Julia stores sparse matrices in a struct that looks like this

```
struct SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer} <: AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti}
    m::Int                  # Number of rows
    n::Int                  # Number of columns
    colptr::Vector{Ti}      # Column j is in colptr[j]:(colptr[j+1]-1)
    rowval::Vector{Ti}      # Row indices of stored values
    nzval::Vector{Tv}       # Stored values, typically nonzeros
end
```

In this structure, the column indices are not stored directly, but instead stored in a "column pointer" vector (colptr). This is great for data compression but sometimes it is necessary to have a vector of column indices rather than column pointers. What is the most efficient way to convert column pointers stored within a sparse array into index values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most documented version, I think, would be to use the second element of `findnz`:

```
julia> r2 = sparse([0 100; 0 100])
2×2 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64, Int64} with 2 stored entries:
 ⋅  100
 ⋅  100

julia> findnz(r2)
([1, 2], [2, 2], [100, 100])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with by reverse engineering colptr. I'm not sure if it is the fastest possible algorithm.

```
using SparseArrays
K = sparse(rand(1000, 1000))
colval = Int[i for i=1:K.n for _=K.colptr[i]:K.colptr[i+1]-1]
```